# Using inner classes to achieve thread-safe behavior without synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, class-design, anti-patterns, synchronization

I have some classes that contains both immutable (primitive & references) and mutable data, but mutability come from external writes (another process).

To avoid using `synchronized` on every getters/setters (and around the update operation, atomicity is important) or a `ReadWriteLock`, I came up with this solution that rely on a `volatile` field pointing to a inner class instance:

```
class A {

    private class AData {

        final int foo;

        AData(X x, ...) {
            foo = ...
        } 

   }

   private final int a;
   private final B b;

   private volatile AData data;

   A(int a, B b, X x, Y y, ...) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
       data = new AData(x, y, ...);
       ...
   }

   public int getFoo() {
       return data.foo;
   }

   void update(X x, Y y...) {
       data = new AData(x, y, ...);
   }

}
```

It looks to me as a good compromise for my use case (a lot more reads, from different threads, than updates), but I'm just trying to make sure I didn't fall into a known anti-pattern.

Comment: Your `AData.foo` is not final. I hope it is a typo, otherwise the solution is probably not thread-safe yet.

Comment: Style wise, I think using `AtomicReference<AData>` rather than `volatile` might be better.  It probably makes little difference to actual behaviour (although it will give you a number of extra options for how to make updates, e.g. atomic test and set so that an operation can fail if another thread has made a change while preparing an update), but it makes your *intent* that `data` is changed atomically easier to see, which is particularly important in code like this that can go wrong very easily if a developer misunderstands what it is doing.

Comment: Depending on how it is used, the user of your data type will probably have to synchronize all access anyway, to avoid race conditions between getFoo and update. So you may be making something thread-safe at the wrong level. I am not sure about Java, but volatile is considered deprecated in C++ and bad form in C#.

Comment: @FrankHileman, Re, "Depending on how it is used..."  The reason to use `synchronized` instead of `AtomicReference` would be if there is some _other_ variable that has to always be consistent with the `data` variable.  You would use `synchronized` in that case to ensure that other threads always see _both_ variables change in one atomic step.  But if there's only one variable, and you only want to ensure that other threads always see the most recent version of it,... that's exactly the case that `AtomicReference` (and AtomicEverythingelse) was meant for.

Comment: @jameslarge Correct, I was just pointing out a common error I often find in multithreaded code (synchronizing at the wrong level).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you first build a replacement `AData` object, then atomically update the read-accessible reference so that it points to the newly-created `AData` object.

The idea looks fine to me, as long as there's no more than writer.

With several writers contending to `.update`, I'd make that method `synchronized`. This would only affect writers, never readers.